# Equi-integrable functions, product

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\left\{f_k\right\}_{k=1}^{+\infty}$ be an equi-integrable set of functions such that $f_k\to f$ in $L^{1}(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is it true that if we take any integrable function $g$ from $L^{1}(\Omega)$, for which $\left\{f_k\cdot g\right\}_{k=1}^{+\infty}\subset L^{1}(\Omega)$,$f\cdot g \in L^1(\Omega)$ then the family $\left\{f_k\cdot g\right\}_{k=1}^{+\infty}$ is equi-integrable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true.
Take $\Omega = (0,1/2)$ and
\begin{align*}
 f_k(x) &= \sqrt{k} \, \chi_{(0,1/k)}(x), \\
 f(x) &= 0, \\
 g(x) &= \frac1{x \, \ln^2(x)}.
\end{align*}
Then, $f_k \to f$ in $L^1(\Omega)$ and, thus, $\{f_k\}$ is equi-integrable.
Moreover, $g \in L^1(\Omega)$.

However,
\begin{equation*}
 \| f_k \cdot g \|_{L^1(\Omega)} = \frac{\sqrt{k}}{\ln(k)}
\end{equation*}
is not bounded w.r.t.\ $k$. Thus, $\{f_k \cdot g\}$ is not equi-integrable.